# counter value is not being implemented when threads run

Tags: java, multithreading, count

I've created the following program which runs two threads with the same thread instance. I've initialised a counter and when each of the thread runs, the counter value should be implemented and at the end it should output in console.

```
public class MTThread {

static int count = 0;

public static void main(String arg[]){

    System.out.println("Main started");
    MTThreadInner in1= new MTThreadInner(1,count);
    MTThreadInner in2= new MTThreadInner(2,count);

    in1.start();

    in2.start();
    while (true) {
        try {
             in1.join();
            in2.join();
            break;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Main finished, count = :"+ count);

}}

 class MTThreadInner extends Thread {
         int num; int counter;
         MTThreadInner(int i,int z) {
            counter=z;
            num = i;

         }

        public void run(){
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            yield();
            System.out.println("This ran Thread "+ num);
            counter=counter+1;

         }


    }
```

However the output always shows count as "0":

Main started

This ran Thread 1

This ran Thread 2

Main finished, count = :0

Comment: It should print `count = 0`  Can you explain why you expected the `count` to change at all?

Comment: As thread1 get over, the value is to increase by 1, and after that thread two runs, the value is to increase by too, but I think count value is not being returned

Comment: Each thread is taking it's own local copy of the value 0 and incrementing it to 1.  This is not being shared with `count` or copied anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output should be `count = 0` as you don't change this variable anywhere.

What you do is copy this variable to another field in `MTThreadInner.counter` where each thread changes it's own copy to `1` but this is an entirely unrelated variable.

What you might have expected to do is to increment a shared, thread safe variable.  To do this I suggest making count an AtomicInteger

```
static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

This way you can copy the *reference* to the same shared, thread safe object and when you call `counter.incrementAndGet()` in each thread it will increment this object.

Comment: I dont get it as I am a beginner, can u pls giv me an idea of how the code would look like

Comment: @Splasher you just need to copy the code in my answer and change the type of `counter` AtomicInteger as well so it all compiles.

Comment: i did that and it compiles, however it shows an error on statement 'counter=counter+1'

Comment: @Splasher This is where you use the `counter.incrementAndGet();` instead.

Comment: Thankss alot for the help

Answer (score 1):

> I have created the following program which runs two threads with the same thread instance.

No, you have created a program that runs two threads via *different* instances of the same `Thread` subclass.

> The counter value should be implemented and at the at end it should output in console.

Each instance of your `Thread` subclass has a private `counter` variable, which I'm sure those threads do update (but how could you tell?).  That's unrelated to the static variable `MTThread.count`, which is what you print at the end.